# CSS selector in Swiper js breaks

Tags: swiper.js

I have my swiper component:

```
<swiper [config]="slideOpts">
               <ng-template swiperSlide *ngFor="let unit of Units" class="peeking-slide">
                    <fs-reserved-unit-card [router]="router" [activatedRoute]="activatedRoute" [doRefresh]="doRefresh" [Unit]='Unit' ></fs-reserved-unit-card>
               </ng-template>
           </swiper>
```

with slideOpts being:

```
slideOpts = {
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        spaceBetween: 10
        navigation: {
           nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
           prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
    };
```

or:

```
slideOpts = {
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        spaceBetween: 10
        pagination: {
             el: '.swiper-pagination',
             type: 'bullets',
        },
    };
```

it seems that as soon as I seem to target the CSS selector it breaks, with the pagination if I have "el: x" the pagination bullets simply do not display. With the Navigation "theprevEl: x" and "nextEl: x" also does not display.

is there anything Im missing perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need to pass any css selectors at all as it is swiper angular component not vanilla js as far as i understand based on your code. It creates all elements and attaches all handlers itself.

Basically when you create pagination you just need to pass **true** or **configuration** and it works immediately - pagination renders without you providing classes.

Here is an example https://codesandbox.io/s/great-robinson-meeogx